# SQL Database Tables - check-in / check-out date check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently learning SQL and I'm trying to build Hotel reservation database. This is how I create a table for reservations:

```
CREATE TABLE Reservation
(
    id INT CONSTRAINT res_id PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    check_in DATE CONSTRAINT ch_in CHECK (check_in >= GETDATE()),
    check_out DATE CONSTRAINT ch_out CHECK (check_out >= GETDATE()) 
);
```

Here I'm checking that users can't enter date which is in the past. However, it doesn't prevent such cases - for example:

```
INSERT INTO Reservation (check_in, check_out)
VALUES ('2021-02-22', '2021-02-19')
```

How can I make sure that `check_out` date can not be before `check_in` date?

Comment: You are testing with dates in February 2021, those are NOT in the past

Comment: getdate - are you sure this isn't sqlserver?

Comment: _How can I make sure that check_out date can not be lower than check_in date?_ Test it against `check_in` . You currently dont, you test it against today

Comment: Yes, I understand that It would make sense to compare check_in and check_out dates. However, when I initialize tables with ```check_out DATE CONSTRAINT ch_out CHECK (check_out >= check_in)``` I get this error - CHECK constraint for column 'check_in' references another column, table 'Reservation'. Do you know what is the reason for this error and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Your create table statement is not valid MySQL.  Are you sure you have the database correct?

Comment: PLEASE try and make your Tags RELEVANT to your actual situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume that you are really using SQL Server, because your code is (presumably) running.

I would recommend:

```
CREATE TABLE Reservations (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    check_in DATE,
    check_out DATE,
    CONSTRAINT chk_reservations_check_in CHECK (check_in >= GETDATE()),
    CONSTRAINT chk_reservations_check_out CHECK (check_out >= GETDATE()) 
    CONSTRAINT chk_reservations_check_in_check_out (check_in <= check_out)
);
```

Here are the changes:

- I have really never had the occasion to need a name for the primary key constraint on a table, so I just usually leave it out.
- The `CHECK` constraints using `GETDATE()` work in SQL Server.  However, the equivalent logic does not work in many other databases.  The difference is that SQL Server only validates the data when it is inserted.  In other databases, the constraint is considered "always true".
- The rest are personal preferences:

  - I prefer naming tables in the plural.
  - I prefer including the entity name in the primary key so foreign key references usually have the same name.

Comment: Thanks for great answer! Indeed it helps. I have only one concern. Don't we need to include check_out date as well? In the code snippet you created only check_in but later compare it to check_out which was not initialize.

Comment: @DmitryDev . . . Yes.  That must've gotten deleted in the editing.

Comment: Interesting, I would have put `check_in < check_out` but depends whether you think a reservation lasting 0 seconds is valid... :-)

Comment: @Charlieface . . . "How can I make sure that check_out date can not be before check_in date?"

Comment: Yeah yeah, I know that's what OP asked for, just saying sounds a little daft. No offence sir :-)